# Changing contents of StyleSelect menu in EPiServer TinyMCE 2 (4.7.9)

Tags: c#, tinymce

Since the new version of TinyMCE arrived, I've had to rework many of functions used in the older versions. I find the new version is much better looking and easier to use than the new one.

My question is how do I edit the contents of the `styleselect` in the toolbar. For example I'd like to remove the option of inserting H1 elements.

I've tried the `.Remove()` and `.RemoveMenuItems()` functions without success.
I am looking for answers to the C# version of TinyMCE, not the JavaScript one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the `style_formats` menu should overwrite what's there by default.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/